# Xamarin - How to show a notification in my app? (ContentPage.ToolbarItems)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app where I use the Master-Detail template, in combination with MVVM. It suites my needs quite well. The thing is that I would occasionally show some sort of information in a notification-like style in the top bar of the displayed view. This would sometimes be an error message like "Server not reachable" or "Action not allowed".

The thing is that it seems the only way to put something into that bar is via the `ContentPage.ToolbarItems`, which does not have a DataBinding or any way to be accessed via the ViewModel.

A possible solution I came up with is passing the view as an argument to the ViewModel, and from there do something like `view.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("abc", null, () => { }));`. But this is breaking the MVVM on a quite basic level, as the ViewModel has a reference to the View. It would be possible to mask the view with an interface, but I don't like this solution at all.

So, can I use DataBinding to dynamically add and remove a button to the top bar in a Xamarin Master-Detail app?

Comment: Instead of modifying the Toolbar, I'd look into implementing the notifications with [snackbars](https://material.io/design/components/snackbars.html#usage), as that would be a more proper way in terms of the UX. Or is it a requirement you can't change?

Comment: @TimoSalomäki Agreed, but there would be a valid case for toolbar items if they are actions that can be taken on the content shown in the detail page (for example delete if it's not readonly)

Comment: Snackbar is cool, except it disapears automatically. This is less suitable for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Adam Good point, you're right about that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already mentioned, it is never a good idea to have a reference to the view in the viewmodel because it breaks the MVVM pattern. In cases like yours, when binding is not available, a sensible/acceptable approach is to subscribe to the viewmodel from the view in order to update it if the viewmodel changes.

Add something like this to your view:

```cs
ViewModel.PropertyChanged += OnViewModelPropertyChanged; 

...

private void OnViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case nameof(ViewModel.YourProperty):
            // Apply changes to the view here, for example:
            ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem(ViewModel.YourProperty, null, () => { }));
            break;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: You'll probably also need to check if the `ToolbarItems` contains the item. Give the `ToolbarItem` a `Name` and `ToolbarItems.Insert`/`ToolbarItems.Remove` that name as necessary. You'll also probably need to invoke on main thread when editing the UI if you're doing any async, so you can wrap those in `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { // update UI here }`

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just gave a simple example of something that could be done when the property changes, but the actual implementation might need to be a little bit more complex.